# Two 'if's don't make an 'else if'...?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

So I ran into this while programming a looping counter...

```
public void onClick(View view) {

            if(mFactBook.number < mFactBook.mFacts.length){
                mFactBook.number++;
            }

            if(mFactBook.number == mFactBook.mFacts.length){
                mFactBook.number = 0;
            }

            String fact = mFactBook.getFact();
            //Update label with dynamic fact
            factLabel.setText(fact);

            int color = mColorWheel.getColor();
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
            showFactButton.setTextColor(color);

            counter.setText("#" + (mFactBook.number + 1));
        }
```

So basically what this does is runs through and checks

1. is mFactBook.number less than mFactBook.mFacts.length? if yes, than add 1 to mFactBook.number.
2. is mFactBook.number equal to mFactBook.mFacts.length? if yes, than set mFactBook.number to 0.

etc...

but when combined into an if else if statement as so...

```
            if(mFactBook.number < mFactBook.mFacts.length){
                mFactBook.number++;
            } else if(mFactBook.number == mFactBook.mFacts.length){
                mFactBook.number = 0;
            }
```

...the app won't set mFactBook.number to 0 after it hits the max length of mFacts. Why is this? I'm curious as to why putting both checkpoints into one if else if statement doesn't work, but having two separate check points does work.

Comment: Two consequent `if` conditions not equal to `else if`

Comment: You could have run this through a debugger in about 1/4 of the time it took you to type this question.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you change in the first piece of code the `mFactBook.number` within the first `if` block.

Given:

```
mFactBook.number = 0
mFactBook.mFacts.length = 1
```

Then your code does:

```
        if(mFactBook.number < mFactBook.mFacts.length){
            mFactBook.number++;
            // mFactBook.number will become 1
        }
```

Then

```
        // 1 == 1 is true
        if(mFactBook.number == mFactBook.mFacts.length){
            mFactBook.number = 0;
            // and mFactBook.number will be reset to 0
        }
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was trying too hard to refactor my code instead of thinking about the logic behind the if-elseif vs two ifs.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the value you are testing in the first block.

After the `mFactBook.number++` incrementation is done in the first `if` block, the `else` block is not taken. In the first snippet the second `if` testing for `mFactBook.number == mFactBook.mFacts.length` is always executed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that **your mFactBook.number is reaching till mFactBook.mFacts.length-1.**
it is not reaching to the mFactBook.mFacts.length.
Thats why in first case,when you check that

**if(mFactBook.number < mFactBook.mFacts.length){
                mFactBook.number++;**

then mFactBook.number is incremented and it becomes mFactBook.mFacts.length.
So again the next if statement becomes true and 0 is set.

But **in the second case**,after incrementing it does not check again.so It is not set to 0.
Try to check why mFactBook.number is only reaching till mFactBook.mFacts.length-1.
I hope it will solve ur issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is because if you have an `if-else if` block once a statement is true it will ignore the rest. whereas for the `if` blocks every statement is being checked and compared by the system.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an `if ... else if` block once a statement is `true` it will ignore other `else if` blocks. But in case of `if` blocks every statement is checked and compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean androiisGood = true,iOSISGood = true
If(androiisGood){
// do this
}
If(iOSISGood){
// do this
}
```

In above code both block will execute

```
 If(androiisGood){
    // do this
    }
  else If(iOSISGood){
    // do this
    }
```

In above code only If block will execute even both are true. I hope this will be sufficient for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when mFactBook.number == 2 and mFactBook.mFacts.length == 3:

```
       if(mFactBook.number < mFactBook.mFacts.length){
            mFactBook.number++; // mFactBook.number == 3, now they are equal!
        }

        if(mFactBook.number == mFactBook.mFacts.length){ // we check the new value
            mFactBook.number = 0;
        }
```

So, as you see, in the case of two ifs `mFactBook.number++` and `mFactBook.number = 0` are controlled by two different values, namely, the old mFactBook.number and the new mFactBook.number.

In the case of if..else if, they are both controlled by the old mFactBook.number. Therefore the difference.

PS You likely need if..else rather than if..else if

Comment: Thank you, and everyone, for the insight! :)